# Mount a filesystem in a K8S pod without privileged

Tags: permissions, filesystems, mount, aws, kubernetes

I have a K8S deployment loading a volume as raw block (through volumeDevices):

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
...
spec:
  replicas: 1
...
  containers:
  - name: somepod
    image: ubuntu:latest
    command: ["sh","-c", "--"]
    args: ["mount /dev/block /data && while true; do sleep 1000000; done"]
    securityContext:
      privileged: true
    volumeDevices:
    - devicePath: /dev/block
      name: vol
  volumes:
  - name: vol
    persistentVolumeClaim:
      claimName: vol
```

This works as expected.

**What I want to achieve:**

I want to mount /dev/block in the container without having to grant it privileged access (ergo, no root).

I have complete control on the base image, whose default user is 1001, added to a nonroot group.

When k8s adds /dev/block to the container, from what I can tell it assigns it a random group e.g. 993:

```
brw-rw----. 1 root  993 259,  16 Dec 15 09:00 block
```

From my understanding this is out of my control (e.g. I cannot tell k8s to mount it under a known group).

**Things I tried**:

- Formatting the filesystem as ext4, adding a /etc/fstab line `/dev/block /data ext4 user,uid=1001,auto 0 0`
- Adding `securityContext: fsGroup:1001`
- Formatting the filesystem as ntfs adding a /etc/fstab line  `/dev/block /data ntfs user,uid=1001,auto 0 0`
- Installing and using `pmount` in the container. Fails because my user is not part of the /dev/block group
- Using a postStart hook (useless, since it shares the same permissions of the main runtime)
- Using a privileged initContainer to mount the volume from /dev/block to an emptyDir /data. From my understanding the initContainer and the container should share the emptyDir, but since the data lives on the mounted volume this doesn't work.

**Things I've yet to try**:

- the `guestmount` suggested [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/96625/how-to-allow-non-superusers-to-mount-any-filesystem) and [here](https://superuser.com/questions/519824/mounting-ext4-drive-with-specified-user-permission)

A possible point of failure might be my possibly incorrect /etc/fstab settings, because whenever I try to mount as user I still get permission issues on /dev/block regardless.

**Why I'm using a Block volume:**

I'm running EKS and I want to have the data in 'ReadWriteMany' shared across several pods in the same Availability Zone. I've looked into using a EFS volume instead of EBS in io2, but I have price/latency concerns.

**Related questions**:

- [Use "mount -o" with a non-root user](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/365308/use-mount-o-with-a-non-root-user)
- [How to allow non-superusers to mount any filesystem?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/96625/how-to-allow-non-superusers-to-mount-any-filesystem)
- https://superuser.com/questions/519824/mounting-ext4-drive-with-specified-user-permission

Comment: Still untested, but according to this blogpost: https://kubernetes.io/blog/2021/11/09/non-root-containers-and-devices/#see-non-root-containers-using-devices-after-the-fix 
it should be possible to allow this behaviour by modifying containerd's settings